# Zend Framework - adding a custom field to the session handler?

Tags: zend-framework

hey all I'm using the Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable Session handler and I was curious if anyone knows how to best add a custom field to the table that it stores the session data in? for example I'd like to be able to log the username of the person in the sessions table.

Anyone know if that's possible with the Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable?

here's my set up code now..

```
$config = array(
  'name'           => 'session',
  'primary'        => 'id',
  'modifiedColumn' => 'modified',
  'dataColumn'     => 'data',
  'lifetimeColumn' => 'lifetime'
```

);
  Zend_Session::setSaveHandler(new Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable($config));
  Zend_Session::start();

Answer (score 0):

i don' think it's possible, i have been searching for the same thing, but if you look at http://tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/zf/Session/SaveHandler/Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable.class.html i don't see anything one could use,

i guess the way to do it, is to build another table, with session id as one column and any other columns you would want